# How to check input stream is ByteArrayInputStream or its a simple StringInputStream?

Tags: java

I'm Having issues troubleshooting this issue from the past 48 hours and constant googling around for a workaround but I couldn't find any way to solve this issue.

Well, I want to know that How to check input stream is ByteArrayInputStream or it's a simple StringInputStream?

Thanks.

Comment: use the `instanceof` operator

Comment: okay will give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `instanceof` to check the type of an instance. This is valid for any type of instance and not just inputsreams.

for example:

```
if (inputStream instanceof ByteArrayInputStream){
 do something
}

else if(inputStream instanceof StringInputStream){
  do something else
}
```